# AbstractControl.value[data] is retuning undefined in Custom Validator using AbstractControl?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, customvalidator, angular-custom-validators

I'm trying to write cross-field -validation using Abstract Control.
control.value[start] is showing undefined. kindly help me on solving.
working code is here.

app.component.html

```js
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  rangeStart = new FormControl('', {
    validators: [this.MyAwesomeRangeValidator('rangeStart')],
  });
  rangeEnd = new FormControl('', {
    validators: this.MyAwesomeRangeValidator('rangeEnd'),
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      rangeStart: this.rangeStart,
      rangeEnd: this.rangeEnd,
    });
  }

  MyAwesomeRangeValidator(rangeStart: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const start = control.value[rangeStart];
      const end = control.value;
      console.log('start', start, 'end', end);
      let re = /^[1-9]\d*$/;
      if (re.test(start) && re.test(end)) {
        return null;
      } else if (re.test(start) && !re.test(end)) {
        return null;
      } else if (!re.test(start) && re.test(end)) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return {
          range: true
        };
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="rangeStart" placeholder="Range start" type="number">
  <input formControlName="rangeEnd" placeholder="Range end" type="number">
</form>
<div> Valid: {{ form.valid ? '' : '' }} </div>
```

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cross-validation-l5m3xb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get property 'rangeStart' from string.

`const start = control.value[rangeStart];`, where `control.value` is a string. If you want to validate few fields at once then you should put validator to the FormGroup.

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  rangeStart = new FormControl('', {
    validators: [this.MyAwesomeRangeValidator('rangeStart', 'rangeEnd')],
  });

  rangeEnd = new FormControl('', {
    validators: this.MyAwesomeRangeValidator('someField_1', 'someField_2'),
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      rangeStart: this.rangeStart,
      rangeEnd: this.rangeEnd,
    });
  }

  MyAwesomeRangeValidator(
    startControlName: string,
    endControlName: string
  ): ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const start = formGroup.get(startControlName).value;
      const end = formGroup.get(endControlName).value;

      console.log(formGroup, 'start', start, 'end', end);

      let re = /^[1-9]\d*$/;

      if (!re.test(start) && !re.test(end)) {
        return { range: true };
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

UPD: added dynamic form controls names

Comment: ,thanks for your answer.is there a way that I can use if for another formcontrols as well.(custom validator applicable to multiple formcontrols)

Comment: you can pass form controls names as arguments into validator. For your logic you can do this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cross-validation-qsiqn2?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: ihttps://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cross-validation-qsiqn2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts. this code is not matching the condition  if (!re.test(start) && !re.test(end)) {
        return {range: true};
      }
.

Comment: `MyAwesomeRangeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const start = formGroup.get('rangeStart').value;
      const end = formGroup.get('rangeEnd').value;
      console.log(formGroup, 'start', start, 'end', end);
      let re = /^[1-9]\d*$/;

      if (!re.test(start) && !re.test(end)) {
        return {range: true};
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
}` this is matching the condition, but it is taking formControls, can we make it dynamic,to use to for other formcontrols as well, where it should satisfy the condition

Comment: sorry, i'm not really sure about your goal, but try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cross-validation-qsiqn2?file=app/app.component.ts =)